# Wave function runs twice every time it is called

Tags: unity, c#

In my game, once the player enters the room I want to start running my wave script. It should run once, then once all the enemies are dead it should run again. But it's running twice, so it always spawns two waves instead of one.

```
void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(wavecontrols());
    
    enemiesalive = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy").Length + 
    GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy2").Length;
} 

void enemiesSpawn()
{
    if (canspawn == true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < waves[nextwave].amountofenemy1; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(enemy1, Spawners[Random.Range(0, Spawners.Length)].position, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < waves[nextwave].amountofenemybasic; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(basicenemy, Spawners[Random.Range(0, Spawners.Length)].position, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        canspawn = false;
        nextwave++;
    }
}

IEnumerator wavecontrols()
{
    enemiesSpawn();

    if (enemiesalive == 0 && passed == true)
    {
        canspawn = true;
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of things not really great. Lets start with your actual question, why the wave is spawning twice.

- You are starting `wavecontrols`
- `wavecontrols` starts `enemiesSpawn`, spawns enemies and sets canspawn to false
- `wavecontrols` next checks `enemiesalive` -> which is still 0 at this point -> sets canspawn to true again
- `enemiesalive` gets updated in Update
- Update calls `wavecontrols`, canspawn is true and second wave gets called

Thats the flow of your spawner and the reason for calling the double spawn. Now for the things that you might want to rework.

- calling `FindGameObjectsWithTag` in Update is not great. And there is no real need to do so. Your enemiesSpawn function knows how many enemies get spawned. And all you need to include in your spawned enemy is a small piece when it gets destroyed/ killed to decrease the counter.
- `wavecontrols` does not need to be started as a Coroutine, you can simply call it directly
- your enemiesSpawn is repeating itself. What if you have another three types of enemies? Or 5? If you repeat lines of code, that is a usually a sign that you can make it better

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you for the solution and the tips, that's what happens when a newbie tried to program his own system lol. I made it a coroutine so i can add some delay between waves later. I'll work on the things u said

Comment: You can have a delay as well without coroutines, there are a few questions about skill or weapon cooldown that will give you a start how it could look like